# What is wrong with this php script?

Tags: php, arrays, replace, foreach, explode

I want to echo out the $desc with the words in $sq in **bold**. This is what my code looks like:

```
<?php
$desc = "This a sentence witch contains 4 words on is Hello the other is moto the third is hoto and finally but not least nono.";
$sq = "Hello moto hoto nono";
$pieces = explode(" ", $sq);
foreach (array($pieces[0], $pieces[1],$pieces[2],$pieces[3],$pieces[4]) as $item)
    $descr = str_replace($item, "<b>".$item."</b>", $desc);
    echo $descr;
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: "This a sentence" forgot the is

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you don't have five elements (0 to 4) in your `pieces` array, but only 4 (=> 0 to 3). 
Next, you don't need to do this :

```
foreach (array($pieces[0], $pieces[1],$pieces[2],$pieces[3],$pieces[4]) as $item)
```

when you can do

```
foreach ($pieces as $item)
```

With the first point changed, it should work, but you should change both.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$desc = "This a sentence witch contains 4 words on is Hello the other is moto the third is hoto and finally but not least nono.";
$sq = "Hello moto hoto nono";
$pieces = explode(" ", $sq);
foreach ($pieces as $item)
  $desc = str_replace($item, "<b>".$item."</b>", $desc);
echo $desc;
```

There were two errors (I think):

- First, the loop instruction was incorrect.
- The echoed var was incorrect to (`descr` and `desc`).

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There's no $pieces[4].  0 => hello; 3 => nono.